# problems in virtumart cart page and product description page

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I am using Virtuemart 2 and Joomla 2.5 . i have assigned slideshow module in home page, but slide show module is displayed in Cart Page too.  I'm much confused and I have no idea to solve it.

Comment: Modules are displayed based on Itemid, check if Itemid of home page and cart page are same.

Answer (score 0):

Like Shairya said, modules depend on the item ID to determine if they need to display or not. If a page in Joomla does not have a corresponding menu item, then it will inherit the item ID from the page that linked to it. You can do a couple of things to fix your issue. First, you can make a new menu and create a menu item for the VM cart. You don't have to put the menu in a module, it does not need to display for it to work.

You can also install Advanced Module Manager and use the Display on Home Page filter for the slideshow. AMM will not display modules on a page that inherits the home page item ID if you use this filter.